# How to toggle between default home launcher and my application using only buttons?

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I am wondering if it is possible to set the home launcher with buttons instead of manually doing it through settings.
Example there is two buttons(Home and MyApp), clicking on home will bring me back to the default home screen and clicking on MyApp will bring me to my application home screen. I am running on Kitkat 4.4.2.

Comment: you can write  own simple launcher :)  with two buttons and set it as default

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because the device will always show the chooser dialog, do you want to use bla or blabla once only or always.

Comment: how can i trigger that dialog whenever i click on the exit button?

Comment: What i have did is that i set my App as default home page. However, i would like to trigger the dialog whenever i click on the exit button so that i can choose back the default home page that will bring me back to the actual home page. Sure. Thank you @Ms Yvette.